# How I can customize the edit form sonataAdmin

Tags: php, e-commerce, sonata

I need to include a list of children orderElement on the edit order page, but I haven't found good info for this. How can I do it?

I can render block with list orderElement, but it has their route and it doesn't work good.

Order Edit Form
[image: Order Edit form]

OrderElement
[image: OrderElement list]

Comment: As for I know this is not how Sonata works. You either have a separate page for this or you create custom template/action. This is a limitation from Sonata, but with some custom work you might be able to achieve this.

Comment: As far as I understand the `OrderPage` stands in a One-To-Many relation to `OrderElement`. Using the `CollectionType` from SonataCoreBundle you can manage `OrderElement` objects within the admin for `OrderPage`.